# FileNotFound Exception on Opening Sqlite DB Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to open an existing sqlite db on my android project and it's having an Filenotfound exception on second run and one other error on first run.

```
public class SyllabusHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static Context mContext;
    public static final String DB_NAME="dusyllabus";
    public static String DB_LOCATION= "/data/data/com.example.amalaugustine.dusyllabus/databases/";
    private static int DB_VERSION=1;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
public SyllabusHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(context);
    DB_LOCATION=cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/databases/";
    Log.v("DBLOCATIONA",DB_LOCATION);
    this.mContext = context;
    copyDatabase(mContext);
}
public void OpenDatabase(){
    String dbPath=mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    Log.v("dbpatH",dbPath.toString());
   if(mDB!=null && mDB.isOpen()){
        return;
    }
mDB=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_LOCATION,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }



private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        Log.i("Database",
                "New database is being copied to device!");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        int length;
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        try {
            myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_LOCATION + DB_NAME);
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the
            // outputfile
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_LOCATION + DB_NAME);
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myInput.close();
            Log.i("Database",
                    "New database has been copied to device!");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("QuizActivity", e.toString());
            return false;

        }
    }
```

The above code is to open an existing sqlite db on android, when I run the code, I'm getting an error on logcat as

```
10-12 13:50:10.389 9813-9813/com.example.amalaugustine.dusyllabus E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
    PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
    PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
    PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
    PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
    PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
```

When I open the app on running, it crashes and the error on logcat was that the filenotfound exception. I'm trying to open an existing database which is on my database folder inside assets, and I'm not able to open this database, what would be the possible error?
I'm not able to figure out the exact error, Thanks if someone can help me with a code that works to open an existing database from the assets folder.

Comment: What you've said is the logcat showing the error, doesn't show the error. There should be more and it should include the error. Please edit your post to include the full stack-trace (part of the logcat that shows the error).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cause of the **File Not Found** exception is because you are using :-

```
myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_LOCATION + DB_NAME);
```

This will be trying to find the file named `/data/user/0/amalaugustine.example.com.dusyllabus/files/databases/dusyllabus` in the assets folder.

You should probably be looking for just the database file so

```
myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
```

That is assuming that the file named **dusyllabus** is not in a sub-directory of the assets folder but is directly in the assets folder.

**However, you would then have an issue with**

```
myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_LOCATION + DB_NAME);
```

Because, unless the file exists a 2nd File not found exception would occur.

Additionally you are using an incorrect path instead of `/data/user/0/amalaugustine.example.com.dusyllabus/files/databases/dusyllabus`

The path should actually be `/data/user/0/amalaugustine.example.com.dusyllabus/databases/dusyllabus`

***Additionally,the code you are trying to use will result in copying the database from the assets file every time you create an instance of the SyllabusHelper class. As there is no check done to see if the database currently exists.***

### Suggested complete fix :-

I would suggest the following code for **SyllabusHelper.java** :-

```
public class SyllabusHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static Context mContext;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "dusyllabus";
    //public static String DB_LOCATION = "/data/data/com.example.amalaugustine.dusyllabus/databases/"; //<<<<<<<<<< not needed
    public String db_location; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SyllabusHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        //ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context); //<<<<<<<<<< NOT NEEDED
        //DB_LOCATION = cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases/"; //<<<<<<<<<<WRONG
        db_location = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath(); //<<<<<<<<<< recommended way to get the path
        //Log.v("DBLOCATIONA", DB_LOCATION); //<<<<<<<<<< not used
        Log.v("DBLOCATIONB",db_location); //<<<<<<<<<< changed
        this.mContext = context;
        copyDatabase(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        Log.v("ONCREATE","On Create has been called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void OpenDatabase() {
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        Log.v("dbpatH", dbPath.toString());
        if (mDB != null && mDB.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        if (doesDBExist()) return true; //<<<<<<<<<< Check if database already exists
        Log.i("Database",
                "New database is being copied to device!");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        int length;
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        try {
            myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); //<<<<<<<<<< only get according to the file name not the path
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the
            // outputfile
            File newdb = new File(db_location); //<<<<<<<<<< get the file so that it exists
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(newdb); //<<<<<<<<<< uses the file
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myInput.close();
            Log.i("Database",
                    "New database has been copied to device!");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("QuizActivity", e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to check for existence of db file
    //!!NOTE!! does not check that the file is a valid database
    private boolean doesDBExist() {
        File db = new File(db_location);
        if (db.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        File dbdir =  new File(db.getParent());
        dbdir.mkdirs();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Of course you could always utilise the [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)**